# Slow startup in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, startup

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday, but I am struggling with low startup, looking at the web, I found this command...
This is my **systemd-analyze blame**

```
1min 45.559s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
     16.803s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     16.621s snapd.service                                        
     14.686s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
     14.194s fwupd-refresh.service                                
     13.107s fwupd.service                                        
     12.748s dev-sda4.device                                      
     11.411s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
     10.888s accounts-daemon.service                              
      8.994s udisks2.service                                      
      7.258s ModemManager.service                                 
      7.057s NetworkManager.service                               
      6.930s polkit.service                                       
      5.481s dev-loop1.device                                     
      5.302s rsyslog.service                                      
      4.973s dev-loop5.device                                     
      4.573s avahi-daemon.service                                 
      4.571s bluetooth.service                                    
      4.550s iio-sensor-proxy.service                             
      4.192s thermald.service                                     
      4.014s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
      3.934s switcheroo-control.service                           
      3.924s systemd-logind.service                               
      3.922s wpa_supplicant.service                               
      3.629s grub-common.service                                  
      3.326s dev-loop0.device                                     
      3.158s dev-loop3.device                                     
      3.141s dev-loop2.device                                     
      3.139s dev-loop4.device                                     
      3.079s apparmor.service                                     
      3.063s gdm.service                                          
      3.017s gpu-manager.service                                  
      2.915s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
      2.496s systemd-resolved.service                             
      2.382s apport.service                                       
      2.336s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
      2.153s colord.service                                       
      1.920s snapd.seeded.service                                 
      1.801s geoclue.service                                      
      1.577s systemd-sysctl.service                               
      1.557s plymouth-read-write.service                          
      1.460s user@1000.service                                    
      1.167s upower.service                                       
      1.014s systemd-timesyncd.service                            
      1.012s systemd-random-seed.service                          
       959ms systemd-udevd.service                                
       908ms systemd-modules-load.service                         
       836ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
       814ms systemd-journald.service                             
       769ms plymouth-start.service                               
       767ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
       723ms kerneloops.service                                   
       667ms snap-core18-1705.mount                               
       646ms systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service       
       577ms swapfile.swap                                        
       573ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-24.mount               
       539ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
       523ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
       511ms keyboard-setup.service                               
       502ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount              
       477ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
       458ms pppd-dns.service                                     
       396ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount                         
       306ms snap-snapd-7264.mount                                
       303ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-EE80\x2d7926.service
       291ms openvpn.service                                      
       289ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
       277ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
       268ms snap-spotify-41.mount                                
       251ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
       194ms boot-efi.mount                                       
       156ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
       152ms setvtrgb.service                                     
       152ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
       141ms console-setup.service                                
       137ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service      
       106ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
        77ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
        67ms ufw.service                                          
        61ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
        60ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
        59ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
        58ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
        53ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-27.mount               
        44ms snap-core18-1754.mount                               
        17ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
        13ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
        11ms alsa-restore.service                                 
         9ms dev-loop7.device                                     
         9ms dev-loop6.device                                     
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
         3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
       736us snapd.socket
```

So, I see that there are lots of stuff taking too much time.
Is this an error in my installation? Or is this a general problem with Ubuntu 20.04?

Also my **systemd-analyze critical-chain**

The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character. The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

```
graphical.target @2min 12.922s
└─multi-user.target @2min 12.922s
  └─kerneloops.service @42.239s +723ms
    └─network-online.target @41.746s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @27.060s +14.686s
        └─NetworkManager.service @20.000s +7.057s
          └─dbus.service @19.994s
            └─basic.target @19.252s
              └─sockets.target @19.252s
                └─snapd.socket @19.251s +736us
                  └─sysinit.target @19.161s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @18.145s +1.014s
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @15.767s +2.336s
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.354s +11.411s
                          └─systemd-journald.service @3.537s +814ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @3.531s
                              └─-.mount @3.526s
                                └─system.slice @3.526s
                                  └─-.slice @3.526s
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX9uf.png)

Comment: This is not a general problem with 20.04. Add to your question above the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: ok it is done ..